# Slide Up Transitions

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to replicate sliding up transitions in a mobile app. I have several "pages" positioned absolutely on my main div.

If I want a page to be in view, I just set its top to 0. If I want to make it inactive, I set its top to something like 9999px.

This works just fine. Now I want to add some animations to spice it up a little. This is how it looks like so far. All pages have the class .page

```
.page {
    position: absolute;
    top: 9999px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;   
}

.active {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0; 
    z-index: 50;
}
```

When I want to move to a page, I add the class active to it and remove any other pages which have classes as inactive. It works.

I also added a transition of .6s to it so that it becomes:

```
.page {
    position: absolute;
    top: 9999px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

I can see the effect. However, there are two effects happening.

1. When I don't want a page, I remove the class active from it. I can also see that page going down which I don't want.
2. The other page then slides up which is fine.

How do I remove the first effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UnNbv/ (code reproduced below), if you put the transition duration only on active pages, you will get the effect you desire.

Example from fiddle (animates on hover, jumps on mouse out):

```
.test {
    position: relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#FF0000;
}

.test:hover {
    top:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

To apply it to your situation, just apply the transition to the `.active` class instead of the `.page` class.

And to get the reverse effect (animating out but not in), you could use `.page:not(.active)` (the `:not` pseudo-class is supported by everything which supports transitions)

Edit:

If you want to have the new page slide over the top of the old page, `step-end` is your friend (I've often wondered what use it could serve; now I know!). Specifically, code like this:

```
.page {
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transition: top .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: top .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: top .6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: top .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: top .6s ease-in-out;
}
.page.active {
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
}
.page:not(.active) {
    top:100%;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: step-end;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: step-end;
    -o-transition-timing-function: step-end;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: step-end;
    transition-timing-function: step-end;
}
```

(example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NN9b5/)

Comment: Perfect. I used step-end. Only issue is now when the new page slides on top of the old page, I have a close button on the new page, If i clock on it, I have the same effect, obviously, the old page comes from the bottom. But what If I want to simulate a close effect and slide the new page down, i.e, the reverse effect..

Comment: That's a bit much for CSS, and to be honest is a different question; you need to use javascript to dynamically decide whether to use an animation or not. Since you're using jQuery anyway, I suggest looking at `.animate`.

Comment: or if your popup page is always a popup, and never the underneath page, just give it a new class which has the animation as you already have it. It doesn't matter if the under-page is left underneath (it doesn't need to be moved down as long as the popup page has a higher z-index)

Answer (score 0):

The slide down and slide up is happening because the transition is consistently apply to both states.

Its a bit tricky to make the transition apply to only a single state or CSS class, because of the nature of removing a class, if it contains both the transition effect and the property that causes the change its easy to run into a problem.

This is a bit simpler in the case of the hover example from @Dave, because hover is not the initial state of the element, it can contain the transitions.

Here is some code that splits this all up giving you a bit more control, but admittedly may be the long way around...

http://jsfiddle.net/WjRAD/

```
    function switchPages() {
    var pageToMakeInactive = $(".page.active"),
        pageToMakeActive = $(".page.inactive"),
        transitionEndEvent = 
            "transitionend " + 
            "webkitTransitionEnd " + 
            "oTransitionEnd " + 
            "otransitionend ";

    pageToMakeActive
        .addClass("active")
        .removeClass("inactive")
        .one(transitionEndEvent, function(){
            // we only want to remove the transtionable
            // behaviour once the transition has ended
            $(this).removeClass("transitionable");
        });

   pageToMakeInactive
       .addClass("inactive")
       .removeClass("active");

    // must add the transition effects on a different
    // call otherwise they will be applied alongside
    // the position changes and this page will slide down
    setTimeout(function() {
        pageToMakeInactive.addClass("transitionable");
    }, 0)
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this improves on the second example I gave: http://jsfiddle.net/NN9b5/ (click to transition). Also `:hover` is pretty much a drop-in replacement for the `.active` class used by the OP. You can switch one for the other and keep the same logic. I just used hover because it's easier to demo pure CSS with.

Comment: That's really neat (step-end), I tried out using :not and simplifying with a toggle but couldn't get it right, hence the alt route I took, but that was the missing piece.